How to choose dataset_text_field in SFTTrainer hugging face for my LLM model
Note: Newbie to LLM's
Background of my problem
I am trying to train a LLM using LLama3 on stackoverflow c langauge dataset.
LLm - meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B
Dataset - Mxode/StackOverflow-QA-C-Language-40k

My dataset structure looks like so
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['question', 'answer'],
        num_rows: 40649
    })
})

Why dataset_text_field is important?
This feild is crucial as LLM decides which column has to pick and train the model to answer the questions.
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset["validation"],
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="question",  # Specify the text field in the dataset <<<<<-----
    max_seq_length=4096,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
)

Iam assuming if i keep the question then LLM gone pick questions column and train to answer the answers when user asked through prompt?
My assumption is right? I did trained my model for hours with questions but when i observed the response. looks like the responses are most of the questions context.

You might have to format your dataset before training according to llama3 format. This code changes the format of the dataset to the required format:
def formatting_func(example):
    text = (f"<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>\n\n"
            f"{example['question']}<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>"
            f"assistant<|end_header_id|>\n\n{example['answer']}<|eot_id|>")
    return {"text" : text}

training_arguments = SFTConfig(dataset_text_field="text")  # add other training args
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    formatting_func=formatting_func,
    eval_dataset=dataset["validation"],
    peft_config=peft_config,
    max_seq_length=4096,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments
)


You can optionally add <|end_of_text|> at the end of each row in the dataset if you are only tuning this for a single turn.
For reference, I have read through the HuggingFace trl documentation and Meta-llama repository.
Edit:
Unfortunately, your assumption is not correct. You have to give the complete text in the required format to the model and the dataset format is just easier to store, read, and format.

How does the trainer know the part of the text to train the model on? As in I want the model to learn generating the answer only, how does the trainer ensure that?

Any LLM cannot differentiate between a "question" and an "answer". Everything is just a stream of tokens to the model. So we arrange these tokens in a particular pattern to realize the question-and-answer effect (Instruction Tuning).
The pattern is created using special tags, as any others will overlap with the text or code. All the special tags (<|start_header_id|>) are assigned separate token IDs. Whenever these tokens appear in the response, the model behavior changes. Eg.,<|eot_id|> tag in the answer indicates the model to stop generating and wait until the next question <|eot_id|>.

This essentially means you have to train the model on the whole question-and-answer pair and during inference take the question from a user and generate the response. It is important to note that the tags are used even during inference and are abstracted away from the user. To summarize the process, the user gives a query, the query is formatted with user tags along with the assistant header, the formatted query is given to the model as input and the model starts generating auto regressively until <|eot_id|> tag appears, then the response is appended with user heading for the next query.

Yes, I understand that. According to your example, model generates auto regressively given the input. But in the SFTTrainer, we give the all tokens at once. That means we auto regressively generate the user's question, too, before generating the answer, right?

This is exactly why the tags exist. The model will never generate the question, it stops right when the <|eot_id|> tag appears in the answer before it goes into the question part. As for training think of it this way, the question tokens are input features and answer tokens are the labels in a supervised training setup. During inference, you give the question tokens as input and predict the answer tokens. So it is required the provide both features (question tokens) and labels (answer tokens) while training.

I didn't understand what you mean there. Why will <|eot_id|> appear in the answer? Why will it see the answer before seeing the question?
